# How can I insert special characters like ☺☻♥♦♣ in password field which is declared as varchar in sql server

Tags: sql-server

How can I insert special characters like ☺☻♥♦♣ in password field which is declared as varchar in sql server?  
 I can't insert those characters.Suggest me.

Comment: You hash passwords, hash doesn't contain special characters and everything is okay. Or not?

Comment: If I try to save those characters it dispayed as ????? in password column.I didn't use any hashing technique. NVARCHAR also save it as ?????

Comment: if you don't hash passwords, it's the right time to begin :-)

Comment: Yes, save password in `encrypted` format. Till the time try `NVARCHAR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you're trying to do that from management studio? Then you should be using `N'yourtext'` for unicode strings.

```
drop table #temp
GO
create table #temp (
    pwd nvarchar(255)
)
GO

insert into #temp (pwd)
select N'☺☻♥♦♣'

select
    *
from #temp
```